# PageVisibility API events on iOS when using home button

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

I'm trying to get a solution that detects when a tab/page has lost/gained focus. It needs to be consistent across Android Chrome, Windows Surface IE and iOS Safari. Focus and Blur seemed to throw up some pretty inconsistent results, and then I stumbled on to PageVisibility API.

It seems to work for everything I need, except when pressing the 'Home' button on iOS. Reopening Safari shows that no events have been fired. Does anyone have a solution that covers this test case?

Here is an example I was using for testing - specifically the Textarea about half way down the page: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/

Comment: it works for me on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Listening for the events pageshow and pagehide may solve this problem:

`document.addEventListener("pagehide", onchange);`
`document.addEventListener("pageshow", onchange);`

See also: [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)